# displaying search results JAVA ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am supposed to use the method exactly(all my methods have to return void)

```
public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
```

The method will search the `ArrayList<Property>` for properties where the asking price is between the minPrice and maxPrice and add each match to a local `ArrayList<Property>` that will then be passed to another method that has to be

```
displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults)
```

How would I create a local `ArrayList<Property>` that is accessible outside the scope of the first method?(if thats what I am supposed to do)

my instance variable and initialization of ArrayList

```
 private ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
```

my method in AgentListing class

```
public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice){

    ArrayList<Property> searchResults;
    searchResults = new ArrayList<Property>();
    for (Property property : properties){
        if (property.getAskingPrice() > minPrice &&
                property.getAskingPrice() < maxPrice){


            searchResults.add(property);
           
        }
    }
}
```

my display method AgentListing class

```
public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults){


    for(Property result: searchResults) {

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

my driver class that I am trying to access the local arraylist with

```
AgentListings CharlesListings = new AgentListings();

        Property one = new Property("1ListingNumber", "777 Imaginary Drive, Nowhere, British Columbia", 1.00, "Single Family", "House",
            "1.1 Acre", 2007);

    one.setNumberOfBedrooms(1);
    one.setNumberOfBathrooms(1);


    Property two = new Property("2ListingNumber", "777 Imaginary Drive, Nowhere, British Columbia", 2.00, "Single Family", "House",
            "2.2 Acre", 2007);

    two.setNumberOfBedrooms(2);
    two.setNumberOfBathrooms(3);

CharlesListings.addProperty(one);
CharlesListings.addProperty(two);

CharlesListings.searchByPriceRange(1.0, 2.0);

CharlesListings.displaySearchResults(searchResults); //searchResults is not reachable
```

[I added the full instructions to my assignment if I am not clear](https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=28ec9ed4-c6ef-445a-b842-1d59101661d3&fn=1409Assign3.pdf&ct=1594032383548&tl=share-document&rf=link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify ***searchByPrice(...)*** method like this:

```
public ArrayList<Property> searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice){

    ArrayList<Property> searchResults;
    searchResults = new ArrayList<Property>();
    for (Property property : properties){
        if (property.getAskingPrice() > minPrice &&
                property.getAskingPrice() < maxPrice){

              searchResults.add(property);
        }
    }
    return searchResults;
}
```

Now, when it returns searchResults array, you can use the returned value as a parameter for ***displaySearchResults(searchResults)*** method.
Like this:

```
ArrayList<Property> searchResultsList = CharlesListings.searchByPriceRange(1.0, 2.0);
CharlesListings.displaySearchResults(searchResultsList);
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the method as public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice) ? Thank you.

Comment: @Grant Lee
You can create variable of type ArrayList<Property>, inside your driver class, and let the method searchResultsList(...) to modify it. But you would have to make it possible for the method to access that variable.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I create a local ArrayList that is accessible outside the scope of the first method?(if thats what I am supposed to do)

here:

```
public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
```

return a list (searchResults) instead of void...

you can define a temp variable, or just queue the returned value as param to the display method

```
ArrayList<Property> x = searchByPriceRange(min, max);
displaySearchResults(x);
```

or

```
displaySearchResults(searchByPriceRange(min, max));
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know I could define a temp variable in that way.

Comment: is there a way to access the local variable by returning void?

Comment: just a hint for you, read how to return lists without allowing others to change its content.... :)

Comment: I will look into it.  I will try to solve this tomorrow. I have been trying to solve this for the entire day.

Answer (score 1):

`searchResult` is a local variable, so it's not visible outside the method it is declared in. A possible solution would be to change the signature of the `searchByPriceRange` method from:

`public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)`

to

`public List<Property> searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)`.

Now you can return the `searchResults` list, so it can be stored in a variable or passed to another method. Since you only need to pass it to the `displaySearchResults` method, you could write:

`CharlesListings.displaySearchResults(CharlesListings.searchByPriceRange(1.0, 2.0));`